# Visual Studio Code: highlighted imports in python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, python-import

I use Visual Studio Code both on my work Windows laptop, and on my Ubuntu PC at home.

There's a functionality that I can see from my Windows vscode that I'd like to have on my Ubuntu one as well, but can't find whether it's a setting, extension, or something else.

The functionality is this: python imports are highlighted in green, and if they are not used, they are dimmed.

Windows screenshot, how I want it to work:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA1Y0.png]

Ubuntu screenshot, how it currently is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33WqC.png]

Does anyone know where I should look? I'm using the same colour theme on both, Monokai.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably an extension that's doing this. Do you have the same extensions installed on both platforms?

Comment: flake8 extension will tell you if you import something but don't use it. Highlighting part is not done by it, though.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not flake8, that only provided the linting warnings and not the highlighting. 
I've installed the extension Settings Sync and synced settings and extensions of my two installations. 
Can't say for sure, but if it was an extension it probably was fixed by removing the Python Extension Pack and installing Python for VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the linting warnings by pip installing [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/).

You also need to add this setting to your settings.json file:

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not flake8, that only provided the linting warnings and not the highlighting

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing the extension Settings Sync and syncing settings and extensions of my two installations.
If it was an extension indeed, it probably was fixed by removing the Python Extension Pack and installing Python for VSCode.

Comment: For the ones looking for an answer, the extension you're looking for is `Pylance`

Answer (score 0):

As @Łukasz Kwieciński mentions in his comment, the solution was Pylance. Installing Pylance and restarting the VSCode issue fixed the issue